# How to write / optimize this activerecord query?

Tags: sql, activerecord

Just getting started with ActiveRecord and tryin' to figure out how I'd go about doing a specific query. It'd be something equivalent to inputting a list of ingredients, and matching those to recipes those ingredients allow you to make. What would a good schema look like and how would something like this be done?

*UPDATE:*

So how I'm doing it so far is I have two models- ingredients and recipes, which are linked by a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. I'm using the following code to get the output I described, but it just seems too roundabout. If anyone could provide any insights on how to optimize / get this in a single query, would be great.

```
recipes = []
ingredients = ['i2', 'i1']
Recipe.uniq.joins(:ingredients).where("ingredients.name in (?)", ingredients).each do |recipe|
  included_ingredients = recipe.ingredients.take_while { |i| ingredients.include?(i.name) }
  recipes << recipe if recipe.ingredients.size == included_ingredients.size
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A good schema would be:

1. Table `recipe` (recipe_id, recipe_name, etc.)
2. Table `ingredient` (ingredient_id, ingredient_name, etc.)
3. Table `ingredients_recipes` (recipe_id, ingredient_id)

The Table `ingredients_recipes` would be the connecting table.

---

Something like this should do the trick:

```
ingredients_recipes.joins(:recipe, :ingredient).where("ingredients_name = (?)", params[:ingredients])
```

This will join all tables and for a list of ingredients specified by an array.

---

For more info check [THIS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Minor point: the *tables* would be lowercase (like `recipes`) and the models would be uppercase and singular (like `Recipe`). Also, join tables are alphabetical so the default would be `ingredients_recipes`.

Comment: running: `IngredientsRecipes.joins(:recipe, :ingredient).where("ingredients.name = ?", ['i2', 'i1']).all` gives me an error (but if I don't use an array and just a single name it works fine.) Error is: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record

Comment: also- correct me if I'm wrong, but reading through the query interface docs I'm not sure that where statement does what I described. I want to take a list, say [i1, i2, and i3], and match that list to recipes where /all/ of the ingredients required, are provided in that list, not just checking every recipe that includes _one_ of those ingredients.

Comment: error was fixed by using `"ingredients.name in (?)"` but still have the problem I explained above

Comment: @ChrisBolton you say now in the question that it's already doing what you need.